# react-i18next pass value into .json using translation

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next, i18next-http-backend

I followed the article here: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb.

Now I want to know if there is a way to pass an argument into the string pulled from the .json file.

### public/locales/en/translation.json

```
{
  "GREETING": "Hello ${name}, nice to see you."
}
```

### src/i18n.ts

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  // i18next-http-backend
  // loads translations from your server
  // https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    debug: false,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

### src/App

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

function App() {
  const {t} = useTranslation();
  const [name] = useState('John Doe');

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{t('GREETING')}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**currently:** the browser is showing "*Hello ${name}, nice to see you.*"

**What I need:** the browser to show "*Hello John Doe, nice to see you.*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default i18next uses different format prefixes (`{{`) and suffixes (`}}`)

Try writing your translations like this:

```
{
  "GREETING": "Hello {{name}}, nice to see you."
}
```

And the [interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation) variable like this:

```
<p>{t('GREETING', {name: "John Doe")}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pass the variable as the second argument to the "t" function.

```
<p>{t('GREETING', {name: "John Doe")}</p>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Also, I think you need to fix the order of `( { ) }`.

Comment: In the json, I changed `${name}` to `{{name}}`, and now it's working. Thanks. If you update your answer I'll give you credit.